# why jquery change function is not working

Tags: jquery

I have a very simple page but it is not working and I don't understand why.

```
<head>
<script src='js/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>

<script>
    $('#uno').change(function() {alert('ok');});
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form name='input' id='formgraph'>
<select id='uno' name='uno'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</form>
</body>
```

So it should alert ok when I change the value but it is not doing it and I don't understand why.

Comment: Put the script at the end of the body tag the DOM is not ready yet.

Comment: use `$(document).ready()` or run the script after the element has been rendered.

Comment: you forgot to close your <select> tag

Comment: http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put your javascript code either at the end of the document (after the `<body>` tag), or in a `$(document).ready(function(){});`

Like this:

```
<head>
    <script src='js/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='input' id='formgraph'>
        <select id='uno' name='uno'>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
<script>
    $('#uno').change(function() {alert('ok');});
</script>
```

Or this:

```
<head>
    <script src='js/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
    <script> <!-- You might want to put this, too after your </body> -->
        $(document).ready(function()
        {
            $('#uno').change(function() {alert('ok');});
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <form name='input' id='formgraph'>
        <select id='uno' name='uno'>
            <option value='1'>1</option>
            <option value='2'>2</option>
        </select>
    </form>
</body>
```

You might also want to put your javascript into a different file, instead of in the middle of your HTML.

You also had invalid markup, because you didn't close the `<select>` tag, I fixed it in my examples.

Answer (score 1):

You have two options.

You can either use document ready:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#uno').change(function(){
        alert('ok');
    });
});
```

Which will wait until the document is ready before running the code in your script tags.

Or (IMO the better option) is to place your script tag at the end of the body:

```
<head>

</head>

<body>
<form name='input' id='formgraph'>
<select id='uno' name='uno'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</form>

<script src='js/jquery-1.11.0.js'></script>
<script>
    $('#uno').change(function() {alert('ok');});
</script>
</body>
```

This will achieve the same effect with less code. Since the script tag is lower in the document, and the browser reads from top to bottom in order - The contents of the script tag wont run until the rest of the document is ready.

The root of the problem is that you can't select $('#uno') until after it exists in the document.

Answer (score 1):

It's recomended to load the js at the end of the page. You forgot to close the select and the html tags.

```
</head>

<body>
<form name='input' id='formgraph'>
<select id='uno' name='uno'>
<option value='1'>1</option>
<option value='2'>2</option>
</select>
</form>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
    $('#uno').change(function() {alert('ok');});
</script>
</body>
</html>
```